# Custom Timer job does not show up under Job Definitions when installed via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, custom-timer-job

We have created a custom timer job in VS2012 farm project.

The scope is set to Site level and the project is deployed at GAC.

Using VS2012, we can deploy the project and see it come up in the Job Definitions, we can hit RUN NOW and the timer job gets executed (it adds an item to a list).

However, when we package and install & activate the same project using PowerShell and hit RUN NOW nothing happens (time job does not execute). If we attach debugger to OWSTimer and then hit RUN NOW, then the timer job gets executed. What is happening? Why is it working only when we use VS and attach debugger to OWSTimer.exe?

We have logged in to the site and installed the package (PowerShell) using farm admin account.

Foll. is my PoweraShell script: (run as admin)

```
 $oUrl="http://mysite:7676/" 
     $solutionPath="C:\soln\"
    $solution="sampletimer.wsp"
        $path= $solutionPath + $solution 
        Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath $path
        install-spsolution -Identity $solution -GACDeployment -Confirm:$true  Enable-spfeature -identity "sampletimer_MyTimerJobFeatureEventReceiver" -confirm:$false -url $oURL
```

Our timer job is set to scope of SITE, we have packaged the wsp and installed & activated via PowerShell. Then, if we click on RUN NOW then it just wont execute its program (it is supposed to insert an item into a list). However, if we attached VS debugger to OWSTimer.exe, then hit RUN NOW, the timer job code gets executed and list items appears.

This is very confusing as to why SharePoint is behaving like this.. What must be causing this?

Comment: Have you restarted the Timer service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following,

1. Restart the timer service in services.msc
2. Check your web application feature once after deployment.

Comment: what do you mean by Check your web application feature once after deployment. It shows ac active. Yet, under job defn, I cannot see the timer job..

Comment: try to de-activate and activate again after deployed the timer job with web application scope. Check if it throws any error.

Comment: it throws error if I try to deactivate. Foll. are deatails:
Sorry, something went wrong

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 



Technical Details 
 


 



Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 


Correlation ID: 0a3d719c-8659-80de-156d-1ed375e0df19 

Date and Time: 2/5/2014 4:11:56 PM

Comment: ok then retract your solution --> then do IISRESET --> Rebuild it --> Deploy.  If possible try setting the following properties in event receiver feature as ActivateOnDefault="false" AlwaysForceInstall="TRUE".

Comment: When I deploy it works all good; and shows up in the job defns.. But, when I package it and install the wsp it using PowerShell, it wont run, neither show up in job defn.

Comment: Tried your suggestion; same error occurs when trying to deactivate.

Comment: If we package and install the timer job wsp at scope of Site; and add the foll. line to PowerShell at end: Enable-spfeature -identity "sampletimer_MyTimerJobFeatureEventReceiver" -confirm:$false -url $oURL Then, the job definition appears. If we click on RUN NOW then it just wont execute its program (it is supposed to insert an item into a list). However, if we attached VS debugger to OWSTimer.exe, then hit RUN NOW, the timer job code gets executed and list items appears. This is very confusing as to why SharePoint is behaving like this. What must be causing this?

Comment: @Thangaraj Please provide more details in your answer.

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan, Since this task is more related to Administration side, i cant write much details as we do for coding!!

Comment: Surprisingly RUN NOW works when we set ActivateOnDefault="false" AlwaysForceInstall="TRUE. Then publish, install and activate the WSP.

Comment: oh thats great man! cheers!

Comment: If I try to scope the timer job to FARM then it doesnot appear under Job defns.. Is it OK to scope it to SITE? IT works that way!..

Comment: It depends upon your requirement, whether to deploy it in Farm / Site / Web / Web Application levels. If your setting the scope to site level make the feature activation on defalut false. So that you can manually go ahead and activate the feature in which site your timer job application required.

Comment: OK, why is it not showing up under job defn when scope is set to FARM?

Comment: When u set your scope to farm level you cannot see it under job definitions. Since its farm level feature you can see it deployed in CA --> SYSTEM SETTINGS --> MANAGE FARM FEATURES. It will be available. Please Check! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I vaguely remember encountering something like this in the past, and whilst the details escape me, I think that adding the **-Force** parameter to Install-SPSolution resolved the issue. I think this was in relation to features rather than timer jobs, but it might be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug the feature activated, attach vs to this and you will see the error, when you activate a feature via powershell it executes under the context of a different user than if you activate it via central admin, so that might probably the reason.

Comment: After packaging the WSP and installing and enabling via PowerShell, when we hit RUN NOW, the timer job does not execute(it is supposed to add an item to a list). However if we attach debugger to the OWSTimer.exe, and then hit RUN NOW, the timer job executes (it does add an item to list). Why is this.?

Answer (score 0):

Check uls log, find that job title. There could be an error or message. It happened to me.